# Send by email a data created and saved in a variable DataSet(); as attachment in csv or excel extension in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, email, attachment

first of all, I am new to c# and I would appreciate any help or recommendations. In one of the applications, I am working with I have some data that is created from a string SQL string and is saved as a variable in a DataSet(), and what I am trying to accomplish is sent this data that is saved to DataSet(); as an attachment csv extension, here I have both when it creates a file and when I want to send it by email also I don't want to create CSV file physically I just want to send whatever data is saved, by email. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public partial class CreateFile: Page
{
public string CreateData(string cdata)
    {
        string getVals = "";
        try
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            Configuration rootwebconfig;
            rootwebconfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/MyWebSiteRoot");
            var conn = new SqlConnection();
            var cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataReader dr;
            string yesno = "No";
            string theName = "";
            conn.ConnectionString = rootwebconfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ToString();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Select something" + dp_props.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'", conn);
            conn.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Configuration rootwebconfig1;
                rootwebconfig1 = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/MyWebSiteRoot");
                string sql = "Here creates the csv by selecting neccesary columns and calculations";
                var connection1 = new SqlConnection();
                connection1.ConnectionString = rootwebconfig1.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ToString();
                var dataadapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection1);
                var dss1 = new DataSet();
                connection1.Open();
                dataadapter1.Fill(dss1, "csvtable");
                connection1.Close();
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            getVals = ex.ToString();
        }

        return getVals;
    }

public void SendEmail(string props)
    {   
        try
        {
            // Sending the email
            var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("admin@something.com");
            mailMessage.Subject = "This is a test" + props + DateTime.Now +;
            System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(dss1);
            mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            attachment.Name = "csvtable.csv";
            mailMessage.Body = "Something";
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("user1@something.com"));

            mailMessage.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("user1@something.com.com"));
            var smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "host.com";
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username.com", "password");
            smtp.Port = 999;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(mailMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string smsg;
            smsg = ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source project called CsvHelper - you may want to use it to create a csv file from a DataTable in your DataSet - stackoverflow.com/questions/49433486/

*** Updated

```
    var dss1 = new DataSet();
    var table = new DataTable("csvdata");
    dss1.Tables.Add(table);
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Height", typeof(int)));

    var row = table.NewRow();
    row["Name"] = "Rick";
    row["Height"] = 72;

    table.Rows.Add(row);


    Sender.SendEmail("",dss1);  
    
public class Sender
{
    public static void SendEmail(string props, DataSet dss1)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Sending the email
                var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("admin@something.com");
                mailMessage.Subject = "This is a test" + props + DateTime.Now ;

                // writes dataset to xml string, stored in a stream
                dss1.WriteXml(stream);
                
                System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(stream, "text/csv"); // should be text/xml actually
                mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                attachment.Name = "csvtable.csv";
                mailMessage.Body = "Something";
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

                mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("user1@something.com"));

                mailMessage.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("user1@something.com.com"));
                var smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "host.com";
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username.com", "password");
                smtp.Port = 999;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(mailMessage);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string smsg;
            smsg = ex.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The idea is not to create the csv file, I just want to send out by email whatever is saved in this part.  var dss1 = new DataSet();
                    connection1.Open();
                    dataadapter1.Fill(dss1, "csvtable");
                    connection1.Close();      and I cant seem to figure out how to include dss1 data to my email attachment?

Comment: The simplest way to have access to dss1 in SendEmail would be to pass it in a method parameter:

void SendEmail(string props, DataSet dss1)

Also, the following line 
Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(dss1)
will not work because the constructor for Attachment doesnt accept DataSets.

Comment: Updated answer to include change described above

Comment: Thank You, Rick